# Пропадают картинки при скролле Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, picasso, cardview

У меня реализована загрузка картинок в адаптере с помощью библиотеки Picasso, картинки имеют большой размер, при скролле вверх или вниз, видимо из-за того, что карточки пересоздаются, происходит опять подгрузка картинок, в итоге все это выглядит не очень красиво, как можно от этого уйти? Можно ли ограничить количество пересоздаваемых карточек? 
Код адаптера:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<News> news;
    private String URL = null;
    private Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public TextView newsDate;
        public TextView summary;
        public ImageView img_android;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleItem);
            summary = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionItem);
            newsDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
            img_android = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<News> news, Context context) {
        this.news = news;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Picasso p = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .memoryCache(new LruCache(240000))
                .build();

        holder.title.setText(news.get(position).getSummary());
        holder.summary.setText(news.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.newsDate.setText(getDate(news.get(position).getNewsDate()));
        p.with(context)
                .load(news.get(position).getImageUrl())
                .into(holder.img_android);
    }

        private String getDate(long time) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
        String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(time));
        String date = "" + dateString;
        return date;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам либо нужны картинки с меньшим разрешением,  либо используйте `fit()`

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(news.get(position).getImageUrl())
        .fit()
        .centerCrop()
        .into(holder.img_android);
```

Comment: C fit() изображение не появляются вообще и в логах пусто, если без fit()  то в логах: com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:142)
        com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
        com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
        java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
        decoder->decode returned false

Comment: попробуйте тогда .centerCrop() убрать, а в разметке у  imageView добавить атрибуты android:scaleType="centerCrop"(или какой ва нужен) и android:adjustViewBounds="true"